# Heat transfer coefficients - correlation equations for Nusselt number - vertical pipe

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

I need a heat transfer coefficient applicable to free convection of water INSIDE a vertical pipe.  I have the correlation equation from Churchill and Chu, but it is only valid for D/L>=35/Gr^(1/4), where D is the diameter, L is the length of the pipe, and Gr is the Grashof number.  My D/L is 0.07, my Gr is 417200 (calculated using the diameter as the characteristic length), and 35/Gr^(1/4) is 1.37, so I am way out of the validity range.  I'm also quite certain the Churchill and Chu correlation equation applies to heat transfer FROM a vertical pipe to an outside fluid, not the effective heat transfer coefficient of the pipe-water combination.

The temperature difference is ~12C over a 0.5m section of pipe, so I'm fairly certain there is enough natural convection to significantly affect the transfer of heat.

Any suggestions are appreciated.